# On a PayPay form, is it possible to code two select fields (dropdowns)?

Tags: paypal, html.dropdownlistfor

I know how to code related select fields, e.g., color and size for a product, but not sure how to have 2 select fields (dropdowns) for 2 different products. Do I have to code two separate forms? or is there a way to put both in the same form. Here I show the later option, but no dice. Thoughts?

Also, trying to figure out how to code an empty first option as "Select..."

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="buy@mycompany.com"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="MyCompany_BuyNow_Annual_US">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Annual Subscription"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mycompany.com""> 
   <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mycompany.com""> 
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

   <p>U.S. Subscription</p> 
   <select name="os0">
      <option value="">Select a Subscription</option>
      <option value="One year">One year: $26</option>
      <option value="Two years">Two years: $52</option>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Length of Subscription">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Sorry, no selection">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="One year">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="26.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Two years">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="52.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe US">

   <p>U.S. Renewals</p> 
   <select name="os1">
      <option value="">Select a Renewal</option>
      <option value="One year">One year: $26</option>
      <option value="Two years">Two years: $52</option>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Length of Subscription">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Sorry, no selection">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="One year">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="18.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Two years">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="36.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Renew US">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but given the minimal sophistication, I would code that as two forms:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_1312096880_biz@test.com"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="MyCompany_BuyNow_Annual_US">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Annual Subscription"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mycompany.com"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mycompany.com"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

   <p>U.S. Subscription</p> 
   <select name="os0">
      <option value="">Select a Subscription</option>
      <option value="One year">One year: $26</option>
      <option value="Two years">Two years: $52</option>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Length of Subscription">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Sorry, no selection">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="One year">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="26.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Two years">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="52.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe US">
</form> 

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_1312096880_biz@test.com"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="MyCompany_BuyNow_Annual_US">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Annual Renewal"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mycompany.com"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mycompany.com"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">


   <p>U.S. Renewals</p> 
   <select name="os0">
      <option value="">Select a Renewal</option>
      <option value="One year">One year: $18</option>
      <option value="Two years">Two years: $36</option>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Length of Subscription">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Sorry, no selection">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="One year">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="18.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Two years">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="36.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Renew US">
</form>
```